# Не работает код! Помогите понять, в чём ошибка

Tags: c++

Помогите понять, почему не работает данная строка:

```
cin.getline(mas[i].name, 30);
```

Не могу ввести нечего. А мне нужно, чтобы можно было вводить слова через пробелы!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Car
{
    char name[30];
    int year;
};
int main(){
    int a;
    cout << "Enter the collection on auto: ";
    cin >> a;
    Car* mas = new Car[a];
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
    cout << "Proizvoditel: ";
    cin.getline(mas[i].name, 30);
    cout << "Year: ";
    cin >> mas[i].year;
}
cout << endl << "Collection: " << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
    cout << mas[i].name << " " << mas[i].year << endl;
}
delete [] mas;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: вот [тут][1] почитайте


  [1]: http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/2888710.flat

Comment: стоит просто добавить cin.get(); после cin>>a; и cin>>mas[i].year;

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `cin >>` a оставляет в конце знак конца строки, т.е. '\n'.
А `cin.getline(mas[i].name, 30)` читает строку, пока не прочтёт 30 символов, или пока не достигнет конца строки, а у тебя конец строки остался после использования `cin`, поэтому он просто убирает '\n' а след строка, т.е. новая, остаётся не прочтённой.
Решение:
Нужно добавить `cin.get();` перед `cin.getline(...);`

```
cin.get();
cin.getline(mas[i].name, 30);
```

Вот так вот.

Answer (score 1):

Если уж с++, тогда std::getline() -  читает до конца строки, столько сколько есть и удаляет '\n' из входного потока.

```
struct Car{
    std::string name;
    int year;
};

Car car1;
std::getline(std::cin, car1.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Car{
    char name[30];
    int year;
};

int main(){
    int a;
    cout << "Enter the collection on auto: ";
    cin >> a;

    Car* mas = new Car[a];

    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        cout << "Proizvoditel: ";
        cin >> mas[i].name;//cin.getline(mas[i].name, 30);
        cout << "Year: ";
        cin >> mas[i].year;
    }

    cout << endl << "Collection: " << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        cout << mas[i].name << " " << mas[i].year << endl;
    }

    delete [] mas;
    return 0;
}
```